# C/C++ How to access header files?

Tags: linker, header-files

I have added some source (header files) in a common folder (`..\shared\abc`) and my code file from another folder (`..\src\xyz`) has `#include <abc/../foo.hpp>`. I get this error:

> Cannot open Source file error

I can fix that by giving absolute path but that change needs to be done at many place. What should I see to fix this?

Using VC9 `nmake` to compile code. This is a Makefile based project.

Comment: What's the command line getting passed to the compiler look like?

Comment: How can I see that. I type "nmake" only.

Comment: I haven't used `nmake`, but the UNIX variants of `make` usually print the commands it's executing as it executes them.

Comment: Do your include statements really have /../ in the path name or are you just trying to save some typing?  Because two dots like that in a path name mean [one directory level up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx) so `#include <abc/../foo.hpp>` is the equivalent of `#include <foo.hpp>`

Answer (score 1):

If the included files are from some library your code is using, you'll want to specify the include path with a compiler option. For the Visual C++ compiler the command-line option to specify additional include directories is `/I`, e.g.:

```
cl /I ..\shared foo.cpp
```

You'll need to modify the compiler options in your Makefile accordingly.